# How to handle very big OSMdata with Pyrosm

Tags: python, parsing, bigdata, openstreetmap

I use Pyrosm for parsing `*.osm.pbf` files.
On their websites it says "When should I use Pyrosm? However, pyrosm is better suited for situations where you want to fetch data for whole city or larger regions (even whole country)."

However when I try to parse to big `.osm.pbf` files, I get memory problems.
Is there a solution for that, e.g. like chunking in pandas?
Or do I need to split up the file, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution is to split the files up via osmium-tools.